# Double quotes being removed from JSON data when saved via MySQLI

Tags: json, mysqli, double-quotes

I'm using PHP 5.2 and when I use `json_encode` the double quotes are escaped (there's a slash behind them). When I try saving it using `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT ...")` it removes the slashes and when I try to retrieve the JSON object from the table it is invalid due to the double quotes in the strings not being escaped. I've currently got it set to utf8_unicode_ci. I had been using a sqlite2 database and had no problems.

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO the_table (data) VALUES ('$json_data')");
```

an example of the data = 'video "Video Name".'; So it uses double quotes within a single quote string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `$json_data` for inserting.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO the_table (data) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $json_data);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```